# Testing expo sdk 39 but failed on expo-yarn-workspaces

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to build sdk-39 from expo, but failed because of expo-yarn-workspaces with following error. I'm using windows 8.1.
Any advice please, to fix this error?

```
Trace: 
  Error: E:\react\expo-sdk-39\node_modules\@expo\sandbox: Command failed.
  Exit code: 1
  Command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
  Arguments: /d /s /c expo-yarn-workspaces postinstall
  Directory: E:\react\expo-sdk-39\node_modules\@expo\sandbox
  Output:
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
    throw err;
    ^
  
  Error: Cannot find module 'E:\react\expo-sdk-39\node_modules\packages\expo-yarn-workspaces\bin\expo-yarn-workspaces.js'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: []
  }
      at ProcessTermError.MessageError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:186:110)
      at new ProcessTermError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:226:113)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:30281:17)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expo sdk 39 is not available yet.

Currently you can use sdk 38 or wait.

Expo team said that sdk39 will be released this month but iOS 14 came late so we really don’t know.

Please read this article
https://blog.expo.io/the-expo-sdk-39-roadmap-36bf5137e8db